# Are there any other planets like Mogo that have a Lantern ring?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

I’m wondering if there’s another planet that has a certain Lantern ring, like Mogo does?

Comment: Everything remotely related to "sentient planet" and "green lantern" seems to point towards Mogo so far, although I don't know the entirety of DC, so I don't know if Mogo is truly the only one.

Comment: Raga gets the spark of life from a ring, but doesn't have a ring of his own; https://comicvine.gamespot.com/raga/4005-102415/

Comment: Just to say, I read [planet Mongo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mongo_(fictional_planet)) and got bewildered until I read the tags.

Answer (score 10):

[Ranx the Sentient City](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Ranx_(New_Earth)) is a planet that is a member of the Sinestro Corps and has a yellow power ring.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[Greykil](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Greykil_(Green_Lantern_Animated_Series)) is a sentient planet with a *red* power ring, as seen in [*Green Lantern: The Animated Series Vol 1 #12*](https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Green_Lantern:_The_Animated_Series_Vol_1_12)

[image]